# how to reduce the number of regions based on colors in this image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I need to show this image in 3 colors , by giving each similar color region one color. The result should be in 3 colors without escape for any region in the image.

how i can combine the small regions with same color in one region as possible limits

i need to reduce the number of regions.

thanks
[image]

Comment: As a side comment: do you mean **yellow** black and white? because that is definetly not green.

Comment: thanks @AnderBiguri
 ok yellow but i need to reduce the number of regions in the image by combine the small regions with same colors.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already have the regions yourself, else you'd be asking a too broad question, as those super-pixels are hard to get.

While I wont write thw code for you, ill give you the steps needed.

1. Find the average color of each region. Remember to work in HSV, and not RGB. Also, remember that H is circular. `[1 0 0]` and `[0 0 0]` are the same color in HSV.
2. Perform a classification of those colors, by, for example, KNN. Create 3 clusters, and compute the centroids of those clusters. Those will be your 3 colors
3. Convert the 3 centroids and the mean color of each superpixel to `L*a*b*` color space. This space is defined as "closest color is most similar color". Basically, compute the euclidean distance of each of the mean values of the superpixels to the 3 "class colors". The minimum distance class will be the one corresponding to that superpixel.

You can find help on each of these steps easily if you Google/search Stackverflow.

The nice thing of coding it properly is that you can try more colors, say 5 or 6, to see if the image/classification is better. 3 seem like to few colors.

Comment: KNN is not a clustering algorithm.

Comment: thank you for answer , i need to show this image in 3 colors by giving one color to the similar color regions

how i can combine the small regions with same color in one region as possible limits                                                                                           i need to reduce the number of regions.

thanks

Comment: @oun there is too few infomation and you are asking a completely different question. If this helped you accept it and ask a new question with your new problem, always showing a [mcve]

Comment: thanks @AnderBiguri i used JSEG technique to segmented the image , but i need to reduce the number of regions in the final image to classify it based on color.

Comment: @oun repeating the question more times in the comment is not going to make us suddenly answer it. Read again my previous comment and do what it says